# Statistics/Data Analysis Book Recommendation

Tags: resource-recommendations, statistics, data-analysis

I looking for recommendations for textbooks on statistics and data analysis. I am a first-year physics student who just finished a module in data analysis/data science. Even though I did pretty well in it I don't feel like I actually understood a lot of it. The topic was taught in some very confusing ways, especially hypothesis testing. I only got through thanks to the help of a friend who is a math major. However, as I am currently considering my future carrier either in research or going into data science this topic is actually very important for my carrier prospects hence I want to learn and understand it. With that I mean and I don't just want to be able to apply the formula but genuinely understand why and how they work and build an intuition for the topic. Any recommendations on texts which would help me do that?

Comment: SInce there's no one right answer, this kind of question isn't a good fit for Stackexchange. That said, Box, Hunter, and Hunter is a well known text on DOE...which might be more useful for engineers than physicists, but might also give you a good understanding of the basics.

Comment: @ThePhoton There is an exception for the [tag:resource-recommendations] tag; see the guidance in the tag wiki.

Comment: @rob Sorry I forgot to add that. Thank you